# Is there a way to exclude the row_number column from the final result?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) AS rn, p.*
  FROM(
    SELECT * FROM products
  ) p) p2
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 10
ORDER BY rn
```

I don't want the above query to return the rn column.

Comment: Sure. Replace `SELECT * FROM` with the actual columns

Comment: Can't you look up the columns of the `products` table in your DB? `SELECT * FROM products` returns that.

Comment: They are everything in your query results except rn.

Comment: The subquery `SELECT * FROM products` can be anything, that is just an example, and it's out of my control. Imagine the most crazy query you can think of, now put it there. I don't know the columns used.

Comment: No this isn't possible. You must either specify the desired columns explicitly or use `*` and get the extra column. There is no `* - RN` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

As of your sample query you are selecting top 10 records ordered by ProductID. If it is true then the same results can be achieved by the following:

```
select * from
(select * from products order by ProductID)
where rownum <= 10
```

If it is not the results you are expecting then please correct your query (maybe add "PARTITION BY").

Comment: This doesnt yield the same results as the OP's query